# Label the bike parts

Tags: parts

I guess this is probably the most stupid question asked on this community but I want to know about all the parts of a bike. I am a non-native English speaker and am finding it difficult to understand the question and answers here. Would you post a picture or some mnemonic device or anything you find valuable related to bike parts, so I could get the names of all the bike parts in my head permanently. Thank you.

Comment: The terminology index is a good start, but doesn't have one all encompassing diagram, as far as I could find. Here's [a diagram](http://www.jimlangley.net/wrench/wrench_images/bicycle_parts_labeled.jpg) with the majority of the parts labeled.

Comment: @Kibbee - that would be a good addition to the terminology index's question

Comment: @Batman If only there was a way to get it to always show up as the top answer. Perhaps It should be edited into the question itself.

Comment: @Batman Nevermind my comment, I just saw your edit.

Comment: It would help if the correct term was used to describe it as well, searching for "glossary" is not particularly helpful. Terminological inexactitude is egregiously misplaced in such situations.